# Is there a way to allow typing a space before a space in Lyx 2.3 to be able to use the input completeion?

Tags: lyx

So back in older version of Lyx, while it still didn't allow you to type two spaces in a row, if you went back and put the cursor *before* a space and tried to type another space it allowed you to do so. If you moved the cursor without typing anything further, the space was simply deleted, but if you wanted to insert a new word before the next one you could have done so.

In the *new* version of Lyx this is impossible. If the cursor is before a space and hit space, it simply moves the cursor to the right so that you would be right before the next word. Therefore if you want to write a new word you will at first have to juxtapose it to the next one (or the previous one), so God forbid Lyx might not worry you might be up to *typing two spaces in a row*.

Apart from being extremely ugly, this doesn't allow you to use the input completion option since you are not starting a new word. This feature is very convenient for me.

> Is there any way to allow typing a space before a space in newer versions of Lyx? (I'm using 2.3.2-2).

Comment: This sounds like either a bug or poor design/implementation.  It should be reported to the Lyx developers.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you, that makes sense.